# Lookup an EJB Implementation by jndi name

Tags: ejb, jndi

I am new to the jndi namespace and I am trying to lookup my EJB class from a service class through below code

```
InitialContext ctx;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            ctx.lookup("?????");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I really don't have any clue what to put inside lookup. I know that jndi name goes there. But from where can I get the jndi name for my ejb class. I am new to this thing and really can't devote much time in learning JNDI.

Comment: It depends on how you have design your bean, if local, remote, no-interface view. So, the proper answer is to look into the documentation [Accessing Enterprise Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html) and try to elaborate the JNDI name of your bean. Or, much quicker, have a look at the start up log of your application server, there should be an entry regarding the JNDI name of your bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer server log file. When EJb beans are deployed. It looks something like this

**JNDI bindings for session bean named SampleImpl in deployment unit subdeployment "sample-web-1.0.0.war" of deployment "xyz.ear" are as follows:**

***Sample code to lookup an EJB bean.***

```
final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
SampleIf sif = (SampleEJBIf) context.lookup("java:app/sample-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/SampleImpl");
```

**Other ways to define Lookup path**

```
java:global/pms/pms-web-1.0.0/SampleClass!com.etipl.pms.x12.SampleClass
java:app/pms-web-1.0.0/SampleClass!com.etipl.pms.x12.SampleClass
java:module/SampleClass!com.etipl.pms.x12.SampleClass
java:global/pms/pms-web-1.0.0/SampleClass
java:app/pms-web-1.0.0/SampleClass
java:module/SampleClass
```